# Does BleachBit's override files to hide contents work on Ubuntu's filesystem type?

Tags: filesystem, ext4, delete, ext3, bleachbit

In the settings for BleachBit it says that the option labeled `Override files to hide contents` does not work to hide the contents on all filesystems. But it does not elaborate on that. I have Ubuntu systems running on both ext3 and ext4, does it work on them? Also, why wouldn't it work? And if this isn't making this question too broad, then I would also like to know if there is a list of filesystems somewhere which this does and/or doesn't work with.

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.10 with GNOME 3.22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default I think ext3 and ext4 use journaling mode, and overwriting individual files may not work well because the overwriting happens in a different physical part of the drive than the original file. The file cannot be undeleted in a standard way using the file system metadata, but the contents could maybe be found using a search of the disk's free space.

Some options:

1. Disable journaling with ext3/ext4
2. Overwrite the free space with BleachBit
3. Use file encryption or whole drive encryption